# Replace int64 value with "None" based on condition of another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWe9U.png]

Conditions are:

'If there is a value other than -1 in RPoints, then any 0 in kPoints should be treated as "None"

'If there is a value other than -1 in RPoints, then any 0 in WPoints should be treated as "None"

Datatypes are as:

```
kPoints         int64

RPoints         int64

WPoints         int64
```

How to replace -1 with 'None'?
And I guess "None" is not going to be helpful for analysis , so how should I remove those rows containing 'None'?

Comment: You need to change the type of the serie to Object, then it can contain any Python object (and be slower).

Comment: the entire dataframe or that particular column?
Can you share any dummy code?

Comment: Show a [mcve]. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

data

```
   id  kpoints  Rpoints  Wpoints
0   1     1241       -1     1466
1   2        0     1475        0
2   3        0     1586        0
3   4        0       -1        0
```

Use

```
data.loc[(data['Rpoints'] != -1) & (data['kpoints'] == 0), 'kpoints'] = None
data.loc[(data['Rpoints'] != -1) & (data['Wpoints'] == 0), 'Wpoints'] = None
```

Output

```
   id  kpoints  Rpoints  Wpoints
0   1   1241.0       -1   1466.0
1   2      NaN     1475      NaN
2   3      NaN     1586      NaN
3   4      0.0       -1      0.0
```

Simple `data.dropna()` will drop all na rows

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a single column and change its type:

```
df['foo'] = df['foo'].astype(np.object)
```

then:

```
df['foo'][0] = None
```

Do note that this will make any processing on the column slower as the types are now Python objects instead of integers in the array.